# Python Selenium cant find the Add photo and video button element on Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Im trying to upload an image to facebook and im unable to click on the Add photo and video button.

When im looking at the html this is the element im trying to click:

```
<input aria-label="Add Photo or Video" accept="video/*,  video/x-m4v, 
video/webm, video/x-ms-wmv, video/x-msvideo, video/3gpp, video/flv, 
video/x-flv, video/mp4, video/quicktime, video/mpeg, video/ogv, .ts, .mkv, 
image/*, image/heic, image/heif" containerclassname="_5g_r" multiple="" 
name="composer_photo[]" display="inline" role="button" tabindex="0" data- 
testid="media-sprout" type="file" class="_n _5f0v" id="js_17y">
```

im trying to find the elment by id:

```
driver.find_elment_by_id("js_17y").click()
```

and im getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

Comment: please check the element id is constant always and also, check the element is inside frame.

Answer (score 3):

*Facebook* is built through [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) so to `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-label='Add Photo or Video'][name^='composer_photo'][data-testid='media-sprout']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Add Photo or Video' and starts-with(@name, 'composer_photo')][@data-testid='media-sprout']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

your id might getting change everytime.Try use xpath with attribute.
However use `webdriverwait` and `element_to_be_clickable` to click on that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@aria-label="Add Photo or Video"][@name="composer_photo[]"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks guys i was able to find it by the class name trough the parent

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3jk")
```

Comment: although this may work you should use `WebDriverWait` as @DebanjanB has suggested...

Comment: @Udi In the HTML you shared it's **`class="_n _5f0v"`** where did you find `class_name("_3jk")`?

Comment: it was in another element