# Simple program to access Facebook elements using Selenium Python but getting errors

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.fb.com")
driver.find_elements_by_name("email").send_keys("******************")
driver.close()
```

Observation: After execute the program I get error. `send_keys()` and `click()` methods are not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sendkeys are not working in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936403/sendkeys-are-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: What kind of errors show the error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dhanvika/PycharmProjects/Italy/sss.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_name("email").send_keys("******************")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: That was due to find_elements use find_element.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because of this line `driver.find_elements_by_name("email")`. The find_elements command in selenium is used to extract multiple elements with same kind of locators which return a list of objects.

Over here in you case, you are accessing a single element and for the extraction you need to use `driver.find_element_by_name("email")`.

A sample script is given below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.fb.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("******************")
driver.close()
```

Just a additional information, `close()` command closes the window under focus and `quit()` command closes window active in session. So you can use `driver.quit()` command either.

Answer (score 0):

To get an element after travelling to page we tend to wait for an element to be interactable due to page loading wait time. You also use find_elements and not find_element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.fb.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys("*****")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

- you need to find one element not many elements
- you need to give time for things to load
- don't need to close the driver straight away

try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.fb.com")
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("******************")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("******************")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").(keys.Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a lot of things here as follows:

- [`find_elements_by_name()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_name) returns a list with elements if any was found or an empty list if not. But moving further as you are trying to invoke [`send_keys(*value)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) so you must be looking for an [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) and use [`find_element_by_name(name)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_name) instead which Finds an element by name.
- You haven't used any method from the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module so ideally you need to remove the unused import:

  ```
  import time
  ```
- Invoking `https://www.fb.com` through `get()` inturn invokes `https://www.facebook.com/`. But scraping [*Facebook*](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [*TOS 3.2*](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [*Facebook Jail*](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [*Facebook Graph API*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.
- [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/) is built through [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) which is pretty much evident from the presence of the following *keywords* and *tags* within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp):

  - `{"react_render":true,"reflow":true}`
  - `<!-- react-mount-point-unstable -->`
  - `["React-prod"]`
  - `["ReactDOM-prod"]`
  - `ReactComposerTaggerType:{r:["t5r69"],be:1}`

  So, the [dynamically generated *class names* are bound to change after certain *timegaps*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992131/decoding-class-names-on-facebook-through-selenium/55178197#55178197) and you should avoid automating *Facebook*.
- Still if you intend to automate logging into *Facebook* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys("vivek")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("vivek")
    ```
  - **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Logging Facebook using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635190/logging-facebook-using-selenium/45636091#45636091)
- [Why Selenium driver fail to recognize ID element of Facebook login page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741832/why-selenium-driver-fail-to-recognize-id-element-of-facebook-login-page/47746472#47746472)
- [Python Selenium cant find the Add photo and video button element on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684085/python-selenium-cant-find-the-add-photo-and-video-button-element-on-facebook/56684241#56684241)